# Possible to get email attachments in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am writing a CRM app and I have hooked into cloud storage to get access to a users documents so they can 'attach' to 'events' in the app, however I'd also like to get a hook into mail so a user can 'attach' any received email attachments to an event as well. Is this possible?

I have seen examples of sending mail from within an app but nothing about handling incoming mail and attachments.

Comment: For security and privacy reasons an app can't read the users email. You would need the user to send the attachment to your app via "open in" from the mail app https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Comment: Fair comment. Thanks. I'm a little surprised this is still a restriction given todays culture of SaaS. Users gain access to their personal & private documents in 3rd party apps as a matter of course.

Comment: You can access cloud drives such as Google, oneDrive, Dropbox etc no problem using their APIs , but giving an app the ability to go into the users email is never going to happen on iOS. It violates the sandbox.